# text files in a Dir and store the file names in a list python

Tags: python

I am trying to grab all of the text files in a Dir and store the file names in a list so i can send them to a method that runs some Photoshop on the files and exports them in a different format.

This for some reason my counter (count) is giving me an output of 12 (the numbers of characters in the file name :( am i storing the list improperly?

```
    import win32com.client
    import os
    def GetFolder():
   file = open('C:\\appData\\File.txt')
   string = file.readlines()
   path = string[0]
   dirListing = os.listdir(path)
   editFiles = []
   for item in dirListing:
    if ".txt" in item:
        editFiles = item
   count = len(editFiles)
   catch = 0
   print "count= " 
   print count 
   print "Catch= " 
   print catch
   print editFiles
   print '----------------------------------------- 

       while catch <= count:
     print editFiles
     catch +=1
```

i am going to loop threw the method it the while loop

Output

```
 count=
 12
 Catch=
 0
 TextFile.txt
 -----------------------------------------
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
 TextFile.txt
```

Comment: You also really shouldn't mix tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you are over-complicating things.

```
  dirListing = os.listdir(path)
  editFiles = []
  for item in dirListing:
    if ".txt" in item:
        editFiles.append(path+'\\'+item)
  print editFiles
```

Comment: Thank You! I tend to over-complicating things :)

Comment: @jon-crawley. My pleasure. Just don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are storing the list improperly.  You define an empty list but instead of adding items to it, you rebind the name of the list to a single file name, try changing the for loop to the following:

```
editFiles = []
for item in dirListing:
    if ".txt" in item:
        editFiles.append(item)
```